# BeginRenderLink Sitecore Glass Mapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper

I have two fields in Sitecore:

- Read More Link.
- Read More Title.

I'm using sitecore MVC with glass mapper, and I need to make both fields editable from page eidtor, so I'm using this code :

```
<div class="callout-footer">
   <p>
     @using (BeginRenderLink(calloutItem, m => m.ReadMoreLink, new NameValueCollection { { "class", "group-action" } }, isEditable: true))
     {
        <span class="text">@Editable(calloutItem, m => m.ReadMoreTitle) </span>
     }
   </p>
</div>
```

Now I can edit the link, but the title is still not editable. How can I make them both editable from page editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ayman,

There is no reason this shouldn't work and I just duplicated it locally without issue succesfully editing the Link (via the Sitecore Experience Buttons in Page Editor) and the Title (via standard text editing in the Page Editor).  How exactly isn't the title editable? Are you just not able to get into the editing frame while in edit mode?

The only thought I have is that maybe your "Text" class on the span is interfering with Sitecore's page editor markup.  Could you try removing the  and see if you are able to edit the ReadMoreTitle?

Answer (score 0):

Yea I wasn't able to get into iframe, I removed the parent div css when the page mode is "page editing". It seems that happened because there is a conflicts between page editor css and my project css. everything is working fine now.

Thanks.